# Why can't I get a file's size with Net:FTP?

Tags: perl

I cannot get a file's size with Net::Ftp. The error I receive is "file1.csv: No such file or directory." I'm sure the file exists. `$ftp->supported('size')` returned true.  Using the full path ('/otherdir/file1.csv') results in the same error. There are no sub directories in the directory I am using & all of the files have a size >0. What am I doing wrong?  I've stripped my code down to the following snippet -

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::FTP;

my $ftp = Net::FTP->new("host", Debug =>0) or die "couldnt connect: $@";
$ftp->login("username","password") or die "couldnt login: ", $ftp->message;
$ftp->binary;
$ftp->cwd("otherdir") or die "couldn't cwd ", $ftp->message;
my @ftp_files = $ftp->ls();
print scalar(@ftp_files);

foreach  (@ftp_files){
  print $_,"\n";
  my $size= $ftp->size($_) or die $ftp->message;
  print $size,"\n";
}
```

Comment: just a side note, it will also die when file size is zero

Comment: @mpapec thank you. There are ~20 files on the server & I'm positive all have a size >0.

Comment: Can you print the file name before the size (first loop line)? Thx

Comment: @DVK yes & the file names print without issue. `scalar(@ftp_files)` returns the expected count of files also. I can include a list of the file names if needed.

Comment: Maybe the server is broken.

Comment: capture output when debug is enabled `Net::FTP->new("host", Debug =>99)`

Comment: This works for me. As others have noted, enable the `Debug` flag and change the `or die` into something like `or warn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

size() only works for files.  Not folders.  Your code is probably die-ing because it gets a $size of undef for a folder.  It never reaches the files that are there.

Comment: There are no sub directories within the directory I'm using.

Comment: Take out the die and see what happens.

Comment: "Use of uninitialized value $size in concatenation (.) or string at test.pl line 63."

Comment: You can add this before the print  `if (!defined $size) { $size = ''; }`

Comment: I would do `foreach  $file (@ftp_files){
    $n = $ftp->size($file);
    if (!defined $n) { $n = ''; }
    print "file=$file, size=$n\n";
}`

Comment: The file names print, but there are no sizes for any of the files.  I'm positive they are all size > 0.

Comment: You can try `$n = $ftp->_SIZE($file)` that's what $ftp->size() does.  I ran the above code and it worked ok (except for subfolders).  Permission issue?  Try a totally different folder.  See if you can manually ftp in and get see the sizes.  Sorry I gotta leave my computer now.

Comment: Turned out to be a permissions issue. Thank you for the help!